# creation a hive table for unstructed data

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, regexserde

how to create hive table for below data ..??

```
3.94.78.5 - 69827    [15/Sep/2013:23:58:36 +0100] "GET /KBDOC-00033.html HTTP/1.0"
19.38.140.62 - 21475 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:34 +0100] "GET /KBDOC-00033.html HTTP/1.0"
19.38.140.62 - 21475 [15/Sep/2013:23:58:34 +0100] "GET /KBDOC-00033.html HTTP/1.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have got the answer for my above question, thanks

```
create table weblogs4(id String,sal int,time string,gets String)
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex'='^(\\S+)\\s+\\S+\\s+(\\S+)\\s+.(\\S+\\s+\\S+).\\s+.(\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+).');
```